# Adding firebase to app in firebase console stalls on step 4

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the steps to add firebase to our xamarin (forms) apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows.

I have tested this through postman and notifications work fine by sending notifications to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

The question is regarding the firebase console. When adding firebase to the app project it stalls on step 4: "Run your app to verify installation", even though I've run the app several times and tested notifications through http. Any idea why or what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: if i rememebr correctly, there is a button on firebase for it to verify you successfully installed it. look for that

Comment: why are you not skipping it, if it works for you? that window is just a test from firebase side it's not like a necessity that your app should connect or whatever

Comment: I was wondering if I was missing something since it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get some errors or warings in logcat?

Comment: Hi Mate, I'm exactly in that situation? Have you solved that yet or just ignored that step? Please suggest.

Comment: I ended up ignoring it. The notifications work fine in production.

Answer (score 1):

For everybody that still needs to understand how it is possible to finalize the Firebase SDK verification in Xamarin.Forms, all you have to do is :

1. Add your platform(s) specific implementation of Xamarin Firebase Core NuGet

   - [Xamarin.Firebase.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Core)
   - [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core/)
2. Initialize Firebase SDK in each platform. For example, in iOS :

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // ...

    Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

3. Launch your application either on Simulator or an actual device.